# how do I create an appropriate drive for a libvirt virtual machine?

Tags: centos, rhel, virtual-machine, libvirt

I am trying to use `virt-install` to create a CentOS 7 virtual machine in a CentOS 7 host.  Towards that end, I have been reading [the virt-install documentation at the RHEL web site](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/sect-Guest_virtual_machine_installation_overview-Creating_guests_with_virt_install.html), and I have also been reading `man virt-install` and `virt-install --help`.  I saw several types of syntax for the `--disk` argument in the documentation, so I picked one and came up with the syntax below, which is throwing an error.  **How can I create an appropriate virtual drive that can be used by the `virt-install` command?**

Here is what I have so far:

```
[root@localhost home]# virt-install --name=public-centos7 --disk path=/home/publicvm --graphics none --vcpus=2 --memory=2048 --cdrom /media/usb/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso --network bridge=br0 --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel7.0
WARNING  CDROM media does not print to the text console by default, so you likely will not see text install output. You might want to use --location.See the man page for examples of using --location with CDROM media

Starting install...
ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2015-10-08T19:53:08.694875Z qemu-kvm: -drive file=/home/publicvm,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=dir: 'dir' invalid format

Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start public-centos7
otherwise, please restart your installation.
[root@localhost home]#
```

Note that `/home/publicvm` is just a directory within the partition mounted at `/home`.  It uses the `ext4` file system.

Note: The `iso` file is on a usb in `ntfs` format.  I downloaded a library to enable CentOS 7 to `mount` the `ntfs` usb from the terminal, and I checked to make sure I could read the contents of `/media/usb` before running the above commands.  I do not imagine that this is in any way relevant to the ERROR message about the drive, however, I am adding this due to the WARNING about the `cdrom` command above.

Comment: Try giving the `--disk` option a complete filename, not just a directory.  IIRC if the file doesn't already exist, you have to specify the size in GB too.  e.g. `--disk /home/publicvm/myvm.img,size=10`.   and maybe try `--location /media/usb/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso` rather than `--cdrom ...`

Comment: please show `mount | grep /media/usb` and `ls -l /media/usb/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso`

Comment: BTW, you may find the GUI `virt-manager` easier than constructing a valid `virt-install` command-line by hand.

Comment: perms are good, no reason why root shouldn't be able to open that .iso file.  ok, forget about `--location`, go back to `--cdrom`.

Comment: this is best continued in chat.  please join me in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discovered in chat, the solution is:

Copy your .ISO image to `/var/lib/libvirt/images` and run `virt-install` like so:

```
virt-install --name=public-centos7 \
    --disk path=/home/publicvm/some.img,size=10 \
    --graphics none \
    --vcpus=2 \
    --memory=2048 \
    --location /var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso \
    --network bridge=br0 \
    --os-type=linux \
    --os-variant=rhel7.0 \
    --extra-args console=ttyS0
```

If there is a failed previous attempt still running, you need to delete and undefine it first using virsh:

```
virsh destroy public-centos7
virsh undefine public-centos7
```

Comment: Also note --extra-args required to produce the console for configuring the guest OS in a downstream step.

Comment: Why on earth does this work? Been so annoyed, it worked after finding this post.